# Stored procedure to fetch asset details based on input parameters

Tags: mysql

I am writing a stored procedure to fetch details based on `CATEGORY ID` passed into it, if the `CATEGORY ID` passed to it is not null, i am fetching based on `CATEGORY ID` , if the `CATEGORY ID` is null i am fetching all the details whose `CATEGORY ID` is except `3`, can anyone help me in resolving this problem.

My procedure is like:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SearchAssetdetails]
(
@assetCategory as int = null,
@assetType as int = null,
@assetDescription as nvarchar(200) = null,
@purchaseDate as datetime = null,
@validUpto as datetime = null)
as
begin
select ad.CategoryID,ad.AssetTypeId,ad.AssetDetailId,ad.AssetDescription,ad.Cost,ad.IsOwn,ad.LastModifiedby,ad.LastModifiedDatetime,ad.Location,ad.NoofLicences,ad.PurchaseDate,ad.SerialNumber,ad.ValidUpto,ad.VendorId,ad.Version,ad.WarrantyExpirationDate
 from AssetDetails ad where      
(ad.AssetDescription like (case when @assetDescription is not null then  '%'+@assetDescription+'%' else ad.AssetDescription end)        
and ad.CategoryID=(case when @assetCategory is not null then @assetCategory else ad.CategoryID   end)        
and ad.AssetTypeId=(case when @AssetType is not null then @AssetType else ad.AssetTypeId end)        
and ad.PurchaseDate=(case when @purchaseDate is not null then @purchaseDate else ad.PurchaseDate end)        
and ad.ValidUpto=(case when @validUpto is not null then @validUpto else ad.ValidUpto end)
 )  end;
```

Comment: What DBMS do you use mysql, oracle, sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the `AND` condition in where clause, your inputs to other parameters may be mismatching for input `category id` as `null` but replaced with `3`.

First, select records with other parameters and see if any of them fetches a record with category id 3.
I suggest you show us records that have category id as 3, to give us a better picture on data.

Else there is no error I believe.

Comment: ya i found the solution, after fetching the details from database i filtered the result based on category id using LINQ like var res=from asset in assetDetails where asset.categoryID!=3 select asset.